# failed getting value from django .env

Tags: python, django

I'm using Django environ and when I try to get a value from `.env` it raise the following exception

> django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Set the FRONTEND_URL environment variable

I load with the command:

```
env = environ.Env()
environ.Env.read_env()
frontend_url = env('FRONTEND_URL')
```

in the .env file I have:

> FRONTEND_URL=http://127.0.0.1:8000

I tried to add " to the value and the `.env` file is in the same folder `manage.py`.

What is the problem here and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move `.env` file next to the same directory which attached commands:

```
env = environ.Env()
environ.Env.read_env()
frontend_url = env('FRONTEND_URL')
```